# how to print the rdlc report without show in the reportviewer

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer, report

i am developeing a web application, in my app i need to direct print .rdlc on clicking on a button, without viewing the report please let me know if thr is any solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to accomplish this because you can't issue commands to the client from the server to make the computer print, it just doesn't work that way. I think you have to write some kind of browser plugin that would have to be installed on the machine that needs to print.